# Prove if r is the smallest positive integer such that all entries of at least one row of Sr are positive, then rad(G) = r.

Tags: graph-theory

Also prove if m is the smallest positive integer such that all entries of Sm are positive, then diam(G) = m.

So I don't want the proof written out. I was just hoping someone could possibly help me out with making the connection. How does knowing that r is the smallest positive integer for which all entries of at least one row Sr are positive, tell you anything about the radius? I know the radius is the value of the smallest eccentricity. The eccentricity is the greatest distance from a vertex to any other vertex. Do you first have to connect r to the eccentricity?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given a graph G of order n with adjacency matrix A, and given a positive integer k, define the matrix sum $S_k$ to be $S_k$=I+A+$A^2$+...+$A^k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the adjacency matrix then the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ is the number of walks of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.
(see [page 17, Theorem 2.6 of my coursenotes for a proof](http://faculty.cbu.ca/jpreen/math4101.pdf))

Now the $(i,j)$ entry of $S_k$ will be the number of walks of length *at most* $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. Hence for any vertex $v$ of eccentricity $e$ there will be no zeros in the row corresponding to $v$ in $S_e$, and hopefully you can now connect that to the diameter and radius of the graph as you have been asked...